# spring + hibernate class not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, classpath

I have a simple web application that I am trying to get running and am having problems.  I migrated a Java EE 6 application to Spring.  It appears hibernate starts fine, but when Spring attempts to create a named bean that refers to an entity, I get ClassNotFoundException.

Any ideas why a jar inside WEB-INF/lib of the WAR is not being seen by spring?  Am I having some sort of proxying issue?

Let me know what files you would like to see snippets of, if any.

EDIT: stack trace attached - I modified the fully qualified class names, in the stack trace for brevity.  I also attached my spring beans configuration.  Also, FYI, my entity classes are all in different jar files (by design).  I believe that is causing some problems, but am not sure why.

```
n]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: api/model/principal/Group
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [server.administration.GroupExampleBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: api/model/principal/Group
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1004)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: api/model/principal/Group
    at server.administration.GroupExampleBean.<init>(GroupExampleBean.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: api.model.principal.Group
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 31 more
```

My Spring application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
            xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jpa"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jpa
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jpa/spring-jpa-3.2.xsd">
  <jpa:repositories base-package="examples" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="examples"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionMa## Heading ##nager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <!--<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>-->
    </bean>

    <!--
    can be: HSQL/H2/Derby
    -->
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!--    For some reason the annotations are not being picked up yet -->
    <!--<bean id="startupListener" class="examples.web.application.StartupListener"/>-->

    <!--    Spring will manage the JPA Listeners
    <jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAware" />
    <bean id="auditorAware" class="org.springframework.data.jpa.example.auditing.AuditorAwareImpl" />
    -->

    <!--
    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.springframework.data.jpa.example.repository.simple" />
    -->
</beans>
```

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: Check and see if the contents of the WEB-INF/lib were bundled into your WAR or moved to the exploded directory you start from.

Comment: What's the full stack trace and error message? Usually the message tells you which class it cannot find.

Comment: I already checked the WAR file, they are there.  However, after reviewing hibernate's logs, it doesn't appear hibernate detected any entities since the startup time for detecting annotated classes was 0ms.  I didn't check hibernate any further.

Comment: Maybe the Spring class scanning configuration is incorrect. Did you refactor the fully qualified name (eg: package name) ?

Comment: post your spring beans.xml file and your java files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to specify  in my persistence.xml pointing to the external jars.

Walter